# Tracking Field History on Opportunity Product?

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem

I currently use Opportunity Products for all our opportunities. I know that we currently cannot track changes on the opportunity product fields.  Is there something that someone has already created to do this or someone who could help me with getting this created?

Comment: please [update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/296607/edit) your question to include what you have thought about as alternatives and what problem(s) you face with these. Otherwise I suggest this sort of question is better placed on the Salesforce developer forums. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and the related materials to see why I say this.

Comment: The obvious workaround is to have a "change tracking" object record that holds the ID of the User that changed the value, the ID of the record in which the change happened, the name of the field that was changed and perhaps other details (e.g. string(s) of the old and/or new values for the field). You would create instances of this, in a trigger or process builder flow, for each field you want to record changes against when the field value(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Field History Tracking on the Opportunity Product, however if you're on EE or UE you could create a custom Long Text filed and use Workflow Rule and a Field Update the PRIORVALUE of the file and a DateTime Stamp and User Details of who modified the field.